# Java Executable jar logback-spring.xml does not see the logback.properties file

Tags: java, maven, logging, logback, executable-jar

The issue is that the `logback.xml` file does not see the `logback.properties` file.

I am trying to run an executable jar (we'll call it `foo.jar`) which is built using Maven. When trying to run foo.jar it fails because it cannot locate the `logback.properties` file. This file does exist within the `foo.jar` and is a sibling file to the `logback.xml` file.

I have tried manually moving the `logback.properties` file around within the foo.jar to no avail. But, I discovered if I put a copy of the `logback.properties` file outside of the jar in the directory where the jar is then it sees the properties file and starts up.

Can someone explain how to get foo.jar to look inside itself for the properties file?

Example: lets say that I have `logback.xml` and `logback.properties` file both located in the foo.jar under the path of '`foo/bar`'.

What must I do to have it locate the properties file?

Side note: It is a Spring Boot project, which I honestly know nothing about Spring so I don't know if that is the obstacle that is causing the grief.

My `logback.xml` file refers to the `logback.properties` file by

```
<property file="logback.properties" />
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Logback docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) (has nothing to do with Spring really)

> You may also reference a resource on the class path instead of a file.

```
<configuration>
  <property resource="resource1.properties" />
  ... snip ...
</configuration>
```

This will try to locate the property file in the root of your classpath (that is, in src/main/resources if you're using Maven). the `<property file="..."/>` syntax is to locate files in the filesystem, relative to your application's current working folder, so it correctly locates the file if placed beside your JAR, just like you described.

Comment: I have another question. If I were to specify both <property file..> and <property resource...> would the resource always trump the file or would file trump resource, or is it going to be whatever is defined last?

Comment: Try it, I'm not sure what the behavior would be. Each library usually has its own idea as to what is the correct behavior. That said, I don't think there's a hierarchy of which properties take a priority, so the latter option - "whatever is defined last" is the most likely

Comment: It appears that whatever is listed last will be the one that loads. However, to have both tags in I need to have both files present. So the one referenced by  'file' needs to be on the system, but I just have it blanked out. This is kind of cool because I can define the resource first to use the internal jar properties file and if I want to have it overridden then I just populate the file on the server. Going to try and see if it supports dynamic loading in this way as well.